# Why can't I declare a let variable with the same name as function body in Chrome

Tags: javascript

Chrome 67 (the latest version as of this writing) lets me do this

```
function foo(x, y) {
    var x = 5;
    console.log(x, y);
}
foo(1,2);
// prints 5 2
```

but not this

```
function foo(x, y) {
    let x = 5;
    console.log(x, y);
}
foo(1,2);
// Throws a SyntaxError: Identifier 'x' has already been declared
```

Is this behavior standard-defined?

Comment: if you add `'use strict';` at the top, the first case will fail as well.

It is a standard behaviour defined

Comment: Yes, this behaviour is standard-defined. You cannot have `let`s or `const`s that redeclare parameters.

Comment: Just like how you can do `var x; var x;` and not `let x; let x` [MDN let#Redeclarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Redeclarations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the old `var` keyword you were free to declare a variable multiple times without issues (well... this was an issue by itself).

The `const` and `let` keywords have a better behavior. In your case: you don't need to re-declare `x` as it's already declared as an argument of the `foo` function, so you can assign something to it directly (overriding parameters is not something very clean, but is legit).

Comment: Thank you, Luca. Shouldn't the opening curly brace of the function declaration create a new scope, thus allowing me to redefine x in the inner scope? For example the following works without an error `function foo(x, y) {let a = 5; {let a = 6; console.log(a);}}; foo(1,2);`

Comment: Yes, but `x` is already in that scope, as it's one of the function parameter, so considered inside the scope itself